# How to execute custom command in CMake with "unpolluted" environment?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make

Problem:
I have an `add_custom_command` which calls an external tool that does a build of some external lib via `gmake`. The gmake output is logged into a log file.

CMake uses Unix Makefiles as a generator target and it sets `$(VERBOSE).SILENT`.
This option somehow gets inherited by gmake (probably via `MAKEFLAGS`) called from the tool which was executed in the top level make file generated from `add_custom_command`. As a result, the log file doesn't contain any useful info.

This is not ideal - used CMake generator and its internal options are inadvertently leaked into my external tool. Is there some way to prevent this?

Here is the code in CMakeLists to better illustrate the problem:

```
...
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "<some target name>"
                   COMMAND ${BUILDTOOL_COMMAND} # i.e. buildtool <buildtool args>
                   VERBATIM)
...
```

For which CMake generates `build.make` file with the following:

```
...
# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

...

<some target name>: 
    buildtool <buildtool args>
...
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of this custom command? Did you try modifying the `MAKEFLAGS` passed to `gmake` by passing additional arguments in the custom command?

Comment: @squareskittles it just calls an executable/script which latter calls gmake of the external lib, i.e. something like `buildtool <path_to_lib>`. It has no way to specify MAKEFLAGS (other than through env variable as it seems to be happening here).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _sets `$(VERBOSE).SILENT`_ ?  Sets it how?  To what?  And in what way does that affect the sub-make makefiles?  And when you say "the log file doesn't contain any useful info", what info does it contain if you invoke it directly that is missing when you invoke it through a cmake rule?

Comment: Why *explain* what the code does and what doesn't, when you can just **post** that code (several lines)? It would eliminate many and many clarification questions.

Comment: @MadScientist I don't know. That's just what CMake generates in the Makefiles: `# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:`. Seems like this target is enough to trigger silent mode.

Comment: @Tsyvarev because the code is autogenerated and doesn't really explain anything more than I've already tried. I've added it nevertheless trying to keep the only parts that matter.

Comment: Did you try adding `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` in your CMake file (after the call to `project()`) to enable verbose Makefiles? Does this then propagate to the call to `gmake`?

Comment: @squareskittles if I add that then it does propagate (or at least doesn't propagate the opposite options, as expected). However this is not a solution nor a workaround since I want the CMake output to stay silent. I just don't want it affecting some unrelated processes that just so happen to be spawned wrong the "silent" makefile,

Comment: Understood. For debugging purposes, this would help confirm the fact that the `gmake` environment is being inherited.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is likely happening here is that the value of the `VERBOSE` variable is being exported to the environment of children, including your "buildtool" (whatever that is).  And, your makefiles that are invoked by buildtool *also* use this same variable to control verbose output, so the setting of the `VERBOSE` variable in CMake is causing the same verbosity setting in the makefiles invoked buildtool.

I don't know anything about "buildtool" so I have no idea what recourse you might have for fixing this.

If you were invoking make directly then you could just override it on the command line, something like:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "<some target name>"
                   COMMAND make VERBOSE=1
                   VERBATIM)
```

to force `VERBOSE=1` regardless of the environment setting.

You'll have to figure out how to do a similar thing with "buildtool" I expect.  Maybe it will work to do just that, if "buildtool" forwards variable settings to `make`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `VERBOSE=1` to sub-make has no effect. When your custom command is `make` of any kind, it will receive its silent setup through `MAKEFLAGS` from the top Makefile (the one generated by `cmake`). It's possible to get rid of `--silent` by explicitly setting up `MAKEFLAGS` before calling `make`, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
        env -i MAKEFLAGS=$(subst s,,$(MAKEFLAGS)) make -f Makefile2

$(VERBOSE).SILENT:
```

```
$ cat Makefile2
all:
        echo "In Makefile2: $@"
        echo "MAKEFLAGS = $(MAKEFLAGS)"
```

Output (`-k` is only for check that only `-s` flag is stripped):

```
$ make -k
echo "In Makefile2: all"
In Makefile2: all
echo "MAKEFLAGS = k"
MAKEFLAGS = k
```

Note that top-level `Makefile` is still silent, while sub-makefile is printed as usual.

You could try to update your `COMMAND` of `add_custom_command` accordingly. Working example:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT bar
    COMMAND env "MAKEFLAGS=$(subst s,,$(MAKEFLAGS))" make -f ../Makefile2
    VERBATIM
    )

add_custom_target(foo DEPENDS bar)
```

Output:

```
$ cmake .
...
$ make foo
[100%] Generating bar
make[4]: Entering directory '/path/to/dir'
echo "In Makefile2: all"
In Makefile2: all
echo "MAKEFLAGS = w"
MAKEFLAGS = w
make[4]: Leaving directory '/path/to/dir'
[100%] Built target foo
```